# I am trying to create code for a read function that reads in data from a text file and assigns that data to multiple variables but there is a error

Tags: python-3.5

```
fileid = "SampleData2017.txt"
ID = []
name = []
date_ent = []
level = []
nights = []
points = []
def Read():
    file = open(fileid, "r")
    Record = file.readlines()
    for line in Record:
        line = line.strip(",")
        A,B,C,D,E,F = line.strip() #here is the error
        ID.append(A)
        name.append(B)
        date_ent.append(C)
        level.append(D)
        nights.append(int(E))
        points.append(int(F))
    file.close
Read()
print(ID)
```

Below is the text file data:

```
Gri33415,Griffiths,2015,Gold,35,40000
Smi22316,Smith,2016,Silver,3,7500
Mia56213,Miah,2013,Platinum,140,165000
All78915,Allen,2015,Platinum,120,145000
Hug91714,Huggett,2014,Platinum,150,50000
Sel77617,Selby,2017,Gold,40,45000
San55614,Santus,2014,Silver,12,30000
Lee44213,Leewah,2013,Silver,15,37500
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably meant [`line.split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead of `line.strip()`...

here is a different idea using a [`csv` reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) (your input data is a csv) and `cols = zip(*rows)` in order to access the columns instead of the rows of your data:

```
from csv import reader

with open(fileid, 'r') as csvfile:
    rows = reader(csvfile)
    cols = zip(*rows)
    ID = next(cols)  # or: list(next(cols))
    name = next(cols)
    date_ent = tuple(int(i) for i in next(cols))
    level = next(cols)
    nights = tuple(int(i) for i in next(cols))
    points = tuple(int(i) for i in next(cols))

print(ID)  # ('Gri33415', 'Smi22316', 'Mia56213', ...)
print(name)  # ('Griffiths', 'Smith', 'Miah', ...)
# etc
```

this returns `tuple`s for the moment; if you need list just change the statements to `list(next(cols))`.